# Passing variables from delegate iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, uiapplicationdelegate

im passing an array from my app delegate to a view controller as follows :

```
Delegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.rows = appDelegate.getCourseArray;
```

My question is, when do i release 'appDelegate'? i tried to release it after the variable is passed but that makes a blank screen (Black). I imagine its because im releasing the actual delegate and not the copy, but in this instance, am i supposed to release it?

Answer (score 4):

You don't release it at all as you don't have ownership of it as per Apples [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `new, allco, retain or copy` (NARC) in the line that obtains the `appDelegate` to there is no ownership and no release/autorelease needs or should be issued.